# Test install script on Ubuntu, as if fresh install

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

I have written a setup bash script to install dependencies of a library I wrote. I would like to test this as if I was a user with a fresh installation of Ubuntu. This will confirm that all they need to do is run my setup script and then build the project. The motivation for this being that I may have installed other packages with `apt` that I have forgotten.

I'm looking for something similar to python virtual environment but at the OS level. Would docker be a suitable candidate?

Comment: I think that @JakeGould has the best approach, but there are other options. 1. If you shut down a newly-created Ubuntu VM and copy or zip the directory, you can recreate a new install any time by copying back or extracting the saved VM. 2. You can use a pre-built VM from somewhere like [here](https://www.osboxes.org/ubuntu/). 3. You could even try installing after booting an Ubuntu Live disc.

Comment: Vagrant is exactly what I was looking for. I was able to test my script on different versions of Ubuntu easily!

Comment: Docker would be just fine IMHO... In fact once you have a working container image, you can publish it as a way to compile things with your library...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker would be too opaque for a task like this. [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) is perfectly suited for this. In fact I would recommend using [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) with VirtualBox since the combo allows you to build, destroy, rebuild and redestroy fairly endlessly in a way that is pefectly suited for tasks like this.